# Returning a Range from a Function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have a sub in VBA call another function, which returns a range and is set to a variable.  I am getting a syntax error when I try to run the GetInputs() method.

```
Function GetDataRange(str As String) As Range
' This prompts the user to select a range of data, we will need to call this once for inputs and once for outputs
Dim rRange As Range
 On Error Resume Next
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
        str, _
        Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)
 On Error GoTo 0
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  If rRange Is Nothing Then
   Exit Function
  Else
   rRange.Font.Bold = True
  End If
  GetDataRange = rRange
End Function

Sub GetInputs()
 Dim rg As Range
 Set rg = GetDataRange("Select Inputs:")


End Sub
```

Edit: I added this code:

```
Sub Test()

End Sub
```

When I try to run it I get the same Syntax error with the Sub Test() line highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First glance, you're missing the `Set` keyword in your range assignment statement:

`GetDataRange = rRange`

Instead, it should be:

`Set GetDataRange = rRange`

**Updated** I have run the code and this was the only error I observe. This should fix it.

Personally, I would avoid doing this inside your function body:

```
rRange.Font.Bold = True
```

And instead, put it in your calling routine:

```
Sub GetInputs()
Dim rg as Range
    Set rg = GetDataRange("Select Inputs:")
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then rg.Font.Bold = True
End If
```

This way, you use the function primarily to get a return value, not to perform operations on an object.  But that is a matter of preference mostly.

Comment: Ok, I think my problem is something else then. I have added the Set statement back in and I get the same error.  In fact, I added an empty Sub called Test() and I tried running it and still got the same Syntax Error.

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error, then the VBE should be highlighting which line is causing the error. Please update your original question to include the code you're currently using :)

Comment: Or indicate which line is raising the error. I can probably help.

Comment: I edited my post, the Sub Test() line is highlighted

Comment: Ok, I just cut the 3 functions from the top of the page to the bottom and now it is working...

Comment: OK. well if it is working, you should accept this answer. It's possible you had some other code that was a problem...